# If the diagonal of a positive operator is compact, is the operator itself compact?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with a fixed orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}_n$.  For a bounded operator $T$ on $H$, the *diagonal* of $T$ is the unique operator $D_T$ on $H$ which is diagonal with respect to the above basis, and whose diagonal entries are given by $d_n=\langle T(e_n),e_n\rangle$.  It is well know that if $T$ is positive and $D_T=0$, then necessarily $T=0$.

> Question: If $T$ is positive and $D_T$ is compact, is $T$ necessarily compact?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope. For each $n$ let $T_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix all of whose entries are $\frac{1}{n}$. This is a rank $1$ projection. So $T = \bigoplus T_n$ is a projection with infinite dimensional range, and hence is not compact. But its diagonal entries go to zero as $n \to \infty$, which means that $D_T$ is compact.

Comment: Thanks Nik.  Very nice example!  This means that the natural conditional expectation from the Calkin algebra onto $\ell^\infty/c_0$ is not faithful.  I wonder if there exists one that is faithful...

Comment: Hmm ... I don't think so. In fact I think any such conditional expectation $\Phi$ will take my operator $T$ to $0$. To see this fix $k$ and for $1 \leq i \leq k$ let $P_i$ be the orthogonal projection onto the basis vectors $e_j$ with $j \equiv i$ (mod $k$). Then $\Phi(T) = \Phi(P_1TP_1 + \cdots + P_kTP_k)$, but each $P_iTP_i$ is a compact operator plus something that has norm at most $\frac{1}{k}$, so the same is true of $P_1TP_1 + \cdots + P_kTP_k$. Since $k$ was arbitrary, this shows that $\Phi(T) = 0$.

Comment: This is now beyond my original motivation but I got curious: the diagonal of your operator is compact alright but the diagonal sequence goes to zero very very slowly.  Can you find examples with faster convergence?  Say $\ell^1$?  Another related question is faithfulness of the conditional expectation on the quotient of $B(H)$ by the trace class operators or other Schatten ideals.

Comment: I think these are good research questions for you!

Comment: @Ruy: if the $d_n$ are $l^1$, this means that $T$ is trace class and hence it is in particular compact.

Comment: @Simon, thanks for reminding me of that fact, although it does make me feel bad since this is the kind of stuff I should never forget!

Answer (score 5):

If T also is sparse, i.e.  for some number N then for each i
<Te_i, e_j> is non-zero for at most  N values of j’s,
(and for each j it is non-zero for at most  N values of i’s) then the claim is true.

I have a proof, but I guess this is well known. My own literature search has been unsuccessful, so anyone having a reference will make me happy.

Comment: Hi @Magnus,  this must be another well known fact that I haven't heard of (among many) so feel free to scratch a proof since I'll certainly benefit from it!